# Volley error with mobile app

Tags: mobile, salesforcesdk

I've got a problem for some days and I still cannot solve it.
Here is the problem :

We developed an application which allows user to enter data and submit them to Salesforce. Of course, we can log in and log out.

If I connect to the application for the first time, I'll be able to use application without problem, sending as much data as I want to Salesforce. Problem comes when I logout with an user, and login with the same user.
Then, as soon as I want to send something to Salesforce,

I have an error like

> "IOException : no authentication challenges found" ...

What's really weird is that I can get information from Salesforce, but I can't push data...

From what I read, it happens when servers return an 401 code. But what makes me very confuse is that this error only fires after a logout/login. It seems like logout doesn't work ... (I am using standard SalesforceSDK mobile function -> `SalesforceSDKManager.getInstance().logout(this)`).

I tried doing a fresh install with all latest releases (only tablet is still using `4.1.2`, I can't update it), but problem is still occurring ...

I really don't know where to look for.
Does someone have ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: My bad, just see and didn't even say "Hello" and I can't edit it ! :(

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been discussed [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104482801595232431809/posts/1Lb6oCNbUTu) on the Mobile SDK Google+ community as well.

Try updating the SDK package from npm (latest 3.0.1) and create a brand new project to test. Here's the fix:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/commit/ebd6d8f647c9bbe97b73d842fda983913cc31c47

Comment: @mickael please answer this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66367/geo-location-not-visible