# Geo location not visible

Tags: visualforce, geolocation, google-map

Hi I have used the below code but the map not showing in visualforce page.

**Code:**

```
<apex:page>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>

    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

    <script>

var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

**Source:**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Comment: Did you check the javascript console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code below, there are a few differences:

1. html5 enabled in `<apex:page>`
2. css was applied to map-canvas

   ```
   <apex:page docType="html-5.0">
       <head><title>Geolocation</title>
       <style>          
          #map-canvas {
            height: 600px;
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
       </style>
       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

     </head>

     <body>
       <div id="map-canvas"></div>
     </body>
       <script>

           var map;

           function initialize() {
             var mapOptions = {
               zoom: 6
             };
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                 mapOptions);

             // Try HTML5 geolocation
             if(navigator.geolocation) {
               navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                 var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                                  position.coords.longitude);

                 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   map: map,
                   position: pos,
                   content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
                 });

                 map.setCenter(pos);
               }, function() {
                 handleNoGeolocation(true);
               });
             } else {
               // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
               handleNoGeolocation(false);
             }
           }

           function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
             if (errorFlag) {
               var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
             } else {
               var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
             }

             var options = {
               map: map,
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
               content: content
             };

             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
             map.setCenter(options.position);
           }

           google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
       </script>
    </apex:page>
   ```

The result is on screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Really thaks. now am able to showing. it is showed our correct city location. Is there any possibility to show the location based on the phone number. How to customize this code?

Comment: @Alex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984998/reverse-phone-number-lookup-apis

Comment: I gone though but I dont know how to integrate with above code? Can you guide lit bit.

Comment: I need a current location, when give the phone number.